# How to use sassLoader includePaths in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, webpack, sass

I've found the project I'm working on full of very long relative paths into the shared styles. I want to configure it just like `webpack.config.json` allows:

```
sassLoader: {
   includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./some-folder")]
}
```

But Angular doesn't expose this file, I've found you could eject, but that's not an option here:

> The 'eject' command has been temporarily disabled, as it is not yet
>   compatible with the new angular.json format. The new configuration
>   format provides further flexibility to modify the configuration of
>   your workspace without ejecting. Ejection will be re-enabled in a
>   future release of the CLI.
>
> If you need to eject today, use CLI 1.7 to eject your project.

Is there a way to set a configuration option in Angular and have scss include paths?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the correct way:

**angular.json**

```
"styles": [
  "src/app/core/preloader/preloader.scss",
  "src/styles.scss"
],
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "src/app/shared/styles/app"
  ]
},
```

Comment: Highlighting the necessary only parts would be helpful.